# How to remove Tab item

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I try to remove a `Tab` on a button click. This is my code so far:

```
private void btnCloseTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Would you like to Close this Tab?", "Confirm", 
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        tabControl.Remove(tabControl1.Tab);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well can you put 4 spaces before your private void?

Comment: What type of variables are `tabControl` and `tabControl1`?

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more code? With this no one can work? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabControl` and `tabControl1` names are rather confusing but assuming you need to remove the currently selected tab of a tab control named `tabControl`, you could do this:

```
if (tabControl.SelectedTab != null)
    tabControl.SelectedTab.Dispose();
```

Comment: Please fix your answer, it is not correct.  Remove() is a very dangerous method, it does not dispose the tabpage and it will leak forever.  Correct code is tabControl.SelectedTab.Dispose().